# Joining tables is giving incorrect COUNT(*) values

Tags: mysql

For the longest time I couldn't figure out why an incorrect `COUNT(*)` values were being returned. After incrementally removing parts of my query I finally realized that joining tables were the reason behind the incorrect values.

This is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT `profiles`.`logo` AS logo,
       `companies`.`company_name`,
       `companies`.`url_slug`,
       count(*)
FROM (`companies`)

JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `companies`.`user_id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`
JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`

WHERE `users`.`last_login` IS NOT NULL
  AND `categories`.`category_id` = '3'
  AND `products`.`active` = 1
  AND `products`.`xmp_1` = 1
  AND `products`.`xmp_2` = 1
  AND `profiles`.`field_a` = 1
GROUP BY `companies`.`id`
```

Running this in my SQL program returns 28 rows, but the `COUNT(*)` row returns something like 1400. I'm not sure where to head from here. I need a column returned that returns the 28 instead of 1400.

SQL Fiddle with sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d2d/9

Comment: The fiddle returns no rows

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97d2d/8 Try this. I need the count(*) to be equal to 2

Comment: What are you actually trying to show the count of?

Comment: The amount of rows returned

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need that value in every row? That value will be available to any client that submits that query as metadata on the results.

Comment: It's not the joining, it's the fact that your usage of `group by` is invalid and the statement would have been rejected by every other DBMS.

Comment: Are you aware that `COUNT(*)` will count the number of rows being aggregated, not the number of output rows?  For example, if you have 10 rows of source data, 4 rows with my_id = 1and 6 rows with my_id = 2, then group by my_id, the count will return 4 and 6 respectively, even though you only have 2 output records?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it's legitimate if the company_id is unique in that table, and there is only ever one profile logo per company_id.

Comment: @MatBailie: it would still be rejected by all other DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query works:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT `profiles`.`logo` AS logo,
       `companies`.`company_name`,
       `companies`.`url_slug`
FROM (`companies`)

JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `companies`.`user_id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`
JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`

WHERE `users`.`last_login` IS NOT NULL
  #AND `categories`.`category_id` = '3'
  AND `products`.`active` = 1
  #AND `products`.`xmp_1` = 1
  #AND `products`.`xmp_2` = 1
  AND `profiles`.`field_a` = 1
GROUP BY `companies`.`id`
) AS stuff
```

I think somehow your original `COUNT(*)` is looking at pre-join-condition or pre-grouping amounts.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this with a simple query. Chris Hayes shows a way to do this with sub-queries and there are a variety of ways to do that.

The reason is that aggregation functions (like `COUNT`) only work on the `GROUP` that a row represents... in this case, each row represents the set of results that have the same company id. There's no way for field in a row to show aggregation information that extends beyond its content, in a simple query.

With subqueries, you can generate the first table, and then aggregate over that. Or, you could just use the fact that the total number of rows returned is included as metadata on the data that is sent back to whichever client submitted the query in the first place, thereby removing the need to include it in the data.

Comment: What are the other varieties of ways of doing this?

Comment: They're just going to involve subqueries and are no better than Chris's suggestion.